# Matlab `xcorr(x,y)` for more than two inputs

Tags: matlab

`xcorr(x,y)`returns the cross-correlation of two discrete-time sequences. I would like to know if there is a similar function that applies to more than two discrete-time sequences.

Comment: Afaik a cross correlation for more than two signals is simply not defined. So you would first need to provide a definition of the signal correlation you wish to achieve.

Comment: you mean a higher correlation?

Comment: @bla I'd like to estimate a cross-correlation between, e.g., three or four discrete-time sequences. Maybe Max is right, and this function is not defined for more than two signals? I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the term correlation is accurately defined, so you can use `corrcoef` to obtain the sense of how 3 vectors are correlated, maybe that is what you want? if so then:

```
correlation = corrcoef([V1(:) V2(:) V3(:)]);
```

will reflect the degree of correlation (negative or positive) of the vectors.

Matlab's built-in xcorr is made for a specific case of two-vectors, measuring the similarity between one vector and a time shifted vector. Each time shift yields a scalar, and you loop over all time shifts. you can xcorr(V1,V2), xcorr(V1,V3), xcorr(V2,V3) to find the correlation per time shift between all pairs, and create a 3D map that visualize the degree of similarity as function of the time-shifts.